# User controls are not retaining the old values when loading through ListBox selecteditem in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have recently started using WPF and MVVM approach. I ma getting a problem in the following case. Can someone help me on this?
I have a list box in my MainWindow.xaml. I am trying to load the different user controls for each list box item selection. My MainWindow.xaml looks like below.

> **MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="MoreOnBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoreOnBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl1VM}">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl2VM}">
                <local:UserControl2/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelsCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="ViewModelName" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel.ViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWidnow View model is as below.

> MainWindowVM

```
public class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        this.ViewModelsCollection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelInfo>(new List<ViewModelInfo>()
            {
                new ViewModelInfo("Control1", new UserControl1VM()),
                new ViewModelInfo("Control2", new UserControl2VM()),
            });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelInfo> viewModelsCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelInfo> ViewModelsCollection
    {
        get { return viewModelsCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (viewModelsCollection != value)
            {
                viewModelsCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ViewModelsCollection);

                this.SelectedViewModel = this.ViewModelsCollection[0];
            }
        }
    }

    private ViewModelInfo selectedViewModel;

    public ViewModelInfo SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedViewModel != value)
            {
                selectedViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedViewModel);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class ViewModelInfo : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelInfo(string viewModelName, ViewModelBase viewModel)
    {
        this.ViewModelName = viewModelName;
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;

    }
    private string viewModelName;

    public string ViewModelName
    {
        get { return viewModelName; }
        set
        {
            if (viewModelName != value)
            {
                viewModelName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ViewModelName);
            }
        }
    }

    private ViewModelBase viewModel;

    public ViewModelBase ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (viewModel != value)
            {
                viewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ViewModel);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Each user control has a text box in it. The user control xaml and viewmodels are as below.

> UserControl1

```
<UserControl x:Class="MoreOnBinding.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoreOnBinding"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 

             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="User Control 1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2"  Text="{Binding UC1Text}" Width="100" Height="30"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> UserControl1VM

```
public class UserControl1VM : ViewModelBase
{
    private string uC1Text;

    public string UC2Text
    {
        get { return uC1Text; }
        set
        {
            if (uC1Text != value)
            {
                uC1Text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => UC2Text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The user control1 code file is as below

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The UserControl 2 is same as the user control1 only the name change.
Now coming to my problem, after running the application I clicked the first item of the list box and it loaded the UserControl1 on ContentControl. I have enntered some text say "UC1" in the text box displayed. However if click on the second item of the listbox and agian click on the first item, the text I have entered is lost. I want to retain old text. Can someone look into this and help me out?

Comment: @samar, please don't attempt to make such pointless edits. An edit is supposed to improve a post, *not* just to give you reputation points, or to allow you to style someone else's post the way that *you* prefer. As your edit improved *nothing* in this post, I have rolled it back.

Comment: @Sheridan I have corrected a typo. If you could not identify, feel free to ask me, instead of making such comments. BTW, I don't know about reputation/points. I just need answer which I got below. Thanks to Dennis

Comment: Rahul, unless your name is Samar (to whom my comment is clearly addressed towards), then you can disregard my comment. All the same, please be careful when asking senior members *not to make such comments* as we not only have a right to make *such comments*, but in fact are encouraged to do just that in order to moderate the incorrect behaviour of some junior members on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: data source property is `UserControl1VM.UC2Text`, and the binding is to `UC1Text`. If you'll look at output window, you'll see a binding error.